# Receiving from Azure Event Hub using QPID and Python

Tags: python, azure, amqp, qpid, azure-eventhub

Im trying to use qpid-proton to receive events from an Azure event hub. I am working on an x64 Windows 8.1 machine. At first I tried to install qpid-proton-0.12 but the install failed in testing in Visual Studio.

I then downloaded qpid-python-0.32, which was installed successfully. However, there are no examples of connnecting to the event hubs with qpid. The only examples I can find are using proton.

How would I connected to an Azure Event Hub to receive messages using qpid-python-0.32

Comment: I've tried to install python-qpid-proton-0.12 in Windows 10 and got the same failed result, but in ubuntu it succeed.

Comment: Thanks for trying! I'm not opposed to moving to Ubuntu but I have a lot of legacy Windows code here Id like to keep. I wonder if anyone who uses proton in Windows has run across this thread.

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer, I would like to point out that for now we do not have or offer support in Python (At this moment the IoT Hub SDK does not offer an example of how to connect a client with Python), at your convenient, please feel free to submit a feature request at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot. Such being the case and for the time being, I would suggest that users prototype with one of the supported languages such as Node.js or Java for example.

Comment: Xu, I am well aware that you do not support Python to RECEIVE from event hubs. There is plenty of support to send messages to the hubs. There is also plenty of support to interact with messaging queues in Azure. However, there does seem to be support to send messages to event hubs. Whys is there no support to receive from event hubs?

Comment: On more point to Ming Xu, I am using Event Hubs, not necessarily the IoT SDK. Ive actually been using the Event Hubs for longer than the IoT SDK has been out. Here is the Azure SDK for Python: http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/servicebus.html.

Comment: Event hub is meant for Ingestion of data. It's needed to write your own mechanisms to pull data out, per my understanding, Event Hub on the receive side only supports the AMQP protocol (send side support HTTP and AMQP), so you can receive from python with the help of Apache Qpid Proton-Python library. Please refer to https://gist.github.com/tomconte/87c9fe34a166591c3000 for a sample code.

Comment: Azure has Notification Hub:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/, however that is geared more to a push mechanism to mobile devices. There is the Iot Suite: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-suite-overview/. It is a bundle of Azure services that we manager together that allows users to connect devices to azure and be able to send messages back to those devices. Please note this is a costly service as you are billed for all of the used services.

Comment: Ming Xu,  I think we are having a large miss communication here. You are telling me exactly what I already told you in my first comment and question. I have seem Tom's proton sample code, but proton is not an easy library to install in windows. Do you have an suggestions on using qpid (the pre-compiled python library for windows)? This library does not have the functions that Tom calls in his sample code - ex. Messenger.

Comment: Apologize the misunderstanding at the very beginning, in this case, it is needed to take some time to research while based on the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-python/, we could know
"Work to enable Proton-C with SSL on Windows is underway so check back frequently for updates." I will post my findings later for our specified question in this thread.

Comment: At this moment, I am waiting for our internal discussion results to share their findings. I am already following up internally to expedite this. Please let me know if you have any concerns with this delay.

Comment: Ming Xu, thank you for your support. I look forward to hearing the results of your internal discussion.

Comment: I just got an update internally, quote the key info here for your reference:
As QPID project has been deprecated by the Apache Foundation and Proton is the way to go, it means we must use Proton (either Proton C or Proton J). If we are using Windows then we should follow the build instructions in INSTALL.md. To generate the Visual Studio project files, from the directory where you found this README file: 
 > mkdir build
 > cd build
 > cmake .. 
Should you have any further concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Add one more reference link here: https://github.com/apache/qpid-proton/blob/master/INSTALL.md due to comment window has characters length limited.